# How to create a root element inside a Collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I imported this:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
    "Number" : 400,
    "Page" : 24,
    "DC" : "NE",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
    "Number" : 300,
    "Page" : 14,
    "DC" : "100",
}
```

And i put the data inside an array like this:

```
{Crs:{[
       {Cr: {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
            "Number" : 400,
            "Page" : 24,
            "DC" : "NE",
        }},
       {Cr: {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
            "Number" : 300,
            "Page" : 14,
            "DC" : "100",
        }},
 ]}}
```

I have this data that i importet and I would like to know how I put it inside a my Main element and modeling like this, using aggregate.

```
{Main: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("main1"),
    "Name" : "MainNAme1",
    {Crs:{[
           {Cr: {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
                "Number" : 400,
                "Page" : 24,
                "DC" : "NE",
            }},
           {Cr: {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
                "Number" : 300,
                "Page" : 14,
                "DC" : "100",
            }},
     ]}},
}}
```

Comment: main element is hard-coded or part of document or from another collection?

Comment: @Saravana The main element is in the same collection. I just wanna add it and put the data inside of it.

Comment: can you post the original document as well?

Comment: @Saravana what i imported from the file? i edit the question with more information.

Comment: so  you're hard-coding `Main._id` and `Main.name`?

Comment: yes im creating main.id and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this aggregation

```
db.crs.aggregate(
  [
    {$group : {_id : null, crs : {$push : {cr : "$$ROOT"}}}},
    {$addFields : {"Main._id" : "main1", "Main.name" : "MainNAme1", "Main.crs" : "$crs"}},
    {$project : {_id : 0 , crs : 0}}
  ]
)
```

Comment: Can you explain me the project? why crs:0 and _id:0?

Comment: those are intermediate fields we've created in the group stage, we don't need them to be in output, so adding $project with 0 disables it in output

Comment: Just one question can i move elements from one field to another?

Comment: I try to use addfields but creates a copy of the element

Comment: use $project and disable the old field with 0

Comment: It didnt work the $project as i expected only works if i made the $project right after i addfield.